# Can't connect to the container neither by alias nor by name on the bridge network

Tags: docker

All examples I found online when demonstrating how to connect to another container through alias/name create their own network.

```
# create the network
$ docker network create my-network

# create the containers and connect them to the network
$ docker run --name service-one --network my-network ...
$ docker run --name service-two --network my-network ...
```

> Now within the service-one container we can connect to service-two by
> its by its container name service-two (instead of localhost)! The same
> is true from service-two to service-one using the latter’s alias.

I wanted to do the same **without creating my own network**, using the default `bridge` network. **Is it possible? If not, why?**

I started a container with `--net-alias` and `--name` on the default `bridge` network:

```
docker run --rm --name=wa -dti -p 80:80 --net-alias=webapp docker/getting-started
```

Now from inside the other container I try to connect to it through the default `bridge` network that both containers are part of:

```
docker run --rm curlimages/curl https://webapp
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: webapp

docker run --rm curlimages/curl https://wa
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: wa
```

No luck. But it works perfectly fine when connecting through IP address.

Comment: this is expected as per documentation.

Comment: As a side note, if you're using Docker Compose, it automatically creates a "user-defined bridge network" named `default`, so you can communicate between services without explicitly declaring anything.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has details on this setup.  It doesn't help plain `docker run`, though.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks, yeah, it works with compose

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I wanted to do the same without creating my own network, using the
> default bridge network. Is it possible? If not, why?

Unfortunately, it is not possible quotting from the docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge

**User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.**

*Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias*.

Also from: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services

**DNS Services**

*By default, a container inherits the DNS settings of the host, as defined in the /etc/resolv.conf configuration file. Containers that use the default bridge network get a copy of this file, whereas containers that **use a custom network use Docker’s embedded DNS server***

Comment: I have a related question. I have a container (nginx reverse proxy) with ports 80 and 443 exposed to the internet. I want to proxy to other containers using their internal docker ports and container names so that I don't have to expose their ports to the internet. This all works. Now I have another container which I launch with the docker run command, plus I add --network=proxy-network. This doesn't resolve from nginx. However, when I first run the container without the network flag, and connect it to the proxy-network after it started, it does work. Why is that?

Comment: Ok, now I found it in the Docker manual: You can only connect to one network during the docker run command.

Comment: @LouisK So you solved your issue right? Also if the answer proved useful please upvote.